# What is the Female-Female connector between laptop and antenna?

Tags: networking, antenna

[image]

I want to use the given antenna with my Lenovo Thinkpad such as X60.

Comment: What version model is it? It should be in the specs. I would think it is a SMA as I have seen on other Lenovos.

Comment: The antenna on a ThinkPad is internal and wired directly to the card.  You'd have to hack in the connections; it's not as simple as just installing an adapter or something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you have shown appears to be an [SMA connector](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SMA_connector). However, fitting the right adapter to make something connect will not necessarily mean it will work as intended.

Answer (score 3):

If the laptop has a connector for an external antenna, it will be documented in the system information. Any documentation should also list the type of connector any compatible antenna will need.

Most laptops do not have such connectors as the internal antenna runs around the screen and covers a relatively large area already.